# LP graph in tikz, labeling

Tags: tikz-pgf

i have this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm,thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
    \node[main node] (1) {1};
    \node[main node] (2) [below of=1] {2};

    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [left] {4} (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the one on the left, would love to have the one on the right. Any ideas?
[image]

Ofcourse being able to change the values of the 2 numbers at will :-)

**EDIT** 
If more than than two notes
[image]

Comment: Keep adding your nodes :) `edge node [pos=0.1,left] {0} node [pos=0.9,left] {4} (2);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
       node distance = 2cm, thick, 
    main node/.style = {circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
    \node[main node,
          label={[xshift=-1ex]below:2},
          label={[yshift=1.2ex]right:3}]   (n1) {1};
    \node[main node,
          label={[xshift=-1ex]above:4},
          below=of n1]                  (n2) {2};
    \node[main node,
          label={[yshift=1.2ex]left:5},
          right=of n1]                  (n3) {3};
    \draw   (n1) -- (n2)
            (n1) -- (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** In above MWE I add third node as you ask in your edit of question. You can add labels to node as many as you wish. Their position can be declared with `above`, `below`, `left`, `right`, `above left` etc as well with angles, for example `30`, `45` ...

Comment: Kinda, is it posible to move the numbers closer to the edge? some times i have edges going out at at 45 degree angel. Hopes it makes sence..

Comment: Also, there can be to edges out of one node, i will try to draw something and add it to the question.

Comment: You can manipulate position of labels. For example, with label distance. Since label has the same featires as node, you can also change inner and outer separation, select diferent font etc. See description in TikZ manual, pp. 237 -- 239.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using the `chains` library if you are using a lot of these kinds of nodes.

In the following example, the numbers outside the nodes in black are just regular `label`s with the number representing the angle at which that particular `label` is placed relative to the node. The labels in grey use the `pin` option and indicate which `chain`(s) the node is part of. I've used 2 chains - `main` and `secondary` - with a couple of changes of direction. The numbers inside the nodes reflect the order of construction.

[image: labelled nodes]

Note that it is possible to add an existing node to a chain - this is how the very first node is added to the `secondary` chain after originally being put on the `main` one - and that it is possible to switch away from a chain before resuming it later - this is how the final node is added to the `main` chain, following a switch away from this chain to construct the `secondary` one.

See the manual for further information, including details of how to construct `branch`es which I've not used here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,mult,varwidth]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      auto,
      thick,
      start chain=main going below,
      start chain=secondary going right,
      node distance=20mm,
      every on chain/.style={circle, fill=blue!20, draw, font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries, join},
      every join/.style={thick},
      every label/.append style={font=\sffamily\small},
      every pin/.append style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize, text=gray, align=center},
      every pin edge/.append style={<-, shorten <=2.5pt},
    ]
    \node [on chain=main, label=-100:-100, label=10:10, pin=-45:{on main\\on secondary}] {1};
    \node [on chain=main, label=100:100, label=-170:-170, pin=-0:on main] {2};
    \chainin (main-1) [on chain=secondary];
    \node [on chain, pin=0:on secondary, label=170:170, label=-80:-80] {3};
    \node [on chain, continue chain=going below, pin=0:on secondary\\new direction, label=80:80, label=-80:-80] {4};
    \node [on chain, pin=135:on secondary, label=80:80, label=10:10] {5};
    \node [on chain, continue chain=going right, pin=90:on secondary\\resume previous direction, label=170:170] {6};
    \node [on chain=main, continue chain=going left, pin=-90:on main\\change direction, label=10:10] {7};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```